# NSSplitView xcode like fixed size headers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nssplitview

I want to have 2 subviews in the splitter and a header for each subview on top of it.
something like XCode's utilities side bar

[image]

I need to move 2 splitters togather so the middle subview (header) have a fixed height

Comment: Perhaps it is just its own view with images and changing the view is done in code?